# Google sheets lookup and sum

Tags: google-sheets, sum, lookup

I have a production schedule where cells are filled with text:

Day 1, Day 2 etc.

And I'd like these cells to be associated with values elsewhere in the same sheet.

For example. Day 1 would be 4 (which corresponds to 4 hours).

Then I have to sum these cells/values (Day 1 = 4 + Day 2 = 6) to get a total for each row.

I can't seem to find a way to do all this using one formula. Is it even possible?

Feel free to [check out the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eP_gfRM7uVVv2QTPEw0ylqDMFJjhNPoRDXl8FphUiGQ/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:L2,Formulas!A:B,2,0)))
```

Comment: Yes (+1) seemed to work without the transpose as well? Also I would put in false to avoid possible false match =SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2:L2,Formulas!A:B,2,false)))

Comment: @Tom Guess I was used to arranging the arrays in the same order.  I did leave the "false" intentionally,since the data is already sorted and probably will be sorted(for performance, if data is extrapolated in the future).

Comment: Good point, but actually the data isn't sorted because Day10 should come before Day2 so I would say this is exactly why you have to be very careful.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH, I'm very grateful for your help. Worked perfectly. You're amazing! :)